# C# - Tryinig to do exchange rates in if/else statement and pass argument into method parameters in main function

Tags: c#, methods, arguments, parameter-passing

I am trying to use a method to calculate the exchange rate then pass back that argument to the method in main. I am unsure if i have converted the money properly as i cant figure out what to put into the parameters when calling the method in main.

for example:
exchange(dont know what to put here);

Also unsure if i have done the exchange method correctly. The program runs up to the point of asking which currency the user whats to exchange to, but thats only when i comment out the exchange method. Really stuck, any tips?

I think i might have to assign values to each of the currencies SEK, USD ,EUR but not sure what to do from there...

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

(if i have enetered my code wrong on this question im sorry, not really sure how to make it look any cleaner)

----this is a console application----

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        writeMenu();
        //exchange();
        //exchange(choiceFromCurrency, coiceToCurrency, valueToExchange);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static void writeMenu()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to your next level Currency Converter!");
        Console.WriteLine("---We---Change---Your---Money---For---You---");
        Console.WriteLine(" -------So---You---Dont---Have---To!-------\n\n");

        Console.WriteLine("What is your base currency?\n");
        Console.WriteLine("1 = SEK, 2= USD or 3= EUR?");
        string userInput = Console.ReadLine();

        if (userInput == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen SEK (Swedish Krona)\n");

        }
        else if (userInput == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen USD (United States Dollar)\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen EUR (Euro)\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Which currency would you like to change your money to?\n");
        string userInput2 = Console.ReadLine();
        if (userInput2 == "1")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen SEK (Swedish Krona)\n");
        }
        else if (userInput2 == "2")
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen USD (United States Dollar)\n");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have chosen EUR (Euro)\n");
        }

    }

    public static decimal exchange(decimal currencyToExchangeFrom, decimal currencyToExchangeTo )
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to exchange?\n");
        string amountToExchange = Console.ReadLine();
        decimal amountToConvert = 0;
        decimal.TryParse(amountToExchange, out amountToConvert);
        decimal newValue;

        // SEK
        if(currencyToExchangeFrom == 1)
        {
            // SEK - SEK
            if (currencyToExchangeTo == 1)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("You have your money, go spend it!");

            }

            // sek -usd
            if (currencyToExchangeTo == 2)
            {
                newValue = amountToConvert / 8.50m;
                Console.WriteLine("You now have" + newValue + " in USD");

            }
        }
        //sek - eur
        if(currencyToExchangeFrom == 2)
        {
            amountToConvert / 9.49m;
            Console.WriteLine("You now have" + newValue + " in EUR");

        }
        //  usd - eur
        if (currencyToExchangeFrom == 3)
        {
            amountToConvert * 0.90m;
            Console.WriteLine("You now have" + newValue + " in EUR");
        }
```

Comment: The top part of main function didnt print above but this is the part where i dont know what to write into the () - static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            writeMenu();
            exchange();   ----   here----
            
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

Comment: I'd look into Console.ReadKey(true) in the first part of your program if you're only taking one-key entries -- much easier to filter out unwanted keypresses, allows for ESC to exit, and doesn't require user to hit ENTER)

Comment: @ShannonHolsinger I have Console.ReadKey(); to go at the end of the program. The user will hopefully enter more than one key when i request how much money they want to convert..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some ideas to get you going... I have a feeling this is homework, so I've only done some modest re-working.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        begin();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static void begin()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome to your next level Currency Converter!");
        Console.WriteLine("---We---Change---Your---Money---For---You---");
        Console.WriteLine(" -------So---You---Dont---Have---To!-------\n\n");

        Console.WriteLine("What is your base currency?\n");
        Console.WriteLine("1 = SEK, 2= USD or 3= EUR?");
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyPress = Console.ReadKey(true);
        int uConvertFrom = getUserInput(keyPress);
        if (uConvertFrom > -1)
        {
            switch (uConvertFrom)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen SEK (Swedish Krona)\n");

                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen USD (United States Dollar)\n");

                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen EUR (Euro)\n");

                    break;

            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (uConvertFrom == -2)
            {
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a valid response. Please try again");
                begin();
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Which currency would you like to change your money to?\n");
        keyPress = Console.ReadKey(true);
        int uConvertTo = getUserInput(keyPress);
        if (uConvertTo > -1) {
            switch (uConvertTo)
            {
                case 1:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen SEK (Swedish Krona)\n");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen SEK (Swedish Krona)\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen USD (United States Dollar)\n");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    Console.WriteLine("You have chosen EUR (Euro)\n");
                    break;
            }

        }
        else
        {
            if (uConvertFrom == -2)
            {
                //break;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You didn't enter a valid response. Please try again");
                begin();
            }
        }
        exchange((decimal)uConvertFrom, (decimal)uConvertTo);
    }
    private static int getUserInput(ConsoleKeyInfo keyPress)
    {
        if (keyPress.Key == ConsoleKey.Escape)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Thank you for using. Exiting now.");
            return -2;
        }
        int ret = -1;
        if (int.TryParse(keyPress.KeyChar.ToString(), out ret))
        {

            return ret;
        }
        else
        {

            return -1;
        }
    }
    public static decimal exchange(decimal currencyToExchangeFrom, decimal currencyToExchangeTo)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("How much would you like to exchange?\n");
        string amountToExchange = Console.ReadLine();
        decimal amountToConvert = 0;
        decimal.TryParse(amountToExchange, out amountToConvert);
        decimal newValue = (decimal)0.000;

        // SEK
        if (currencyToExchangeFrom == 1)
        {
            // SEK - SEK
            if (currencyToExchangeTo == 1)
            {

                Console.WriteLine("You have your money, go spend it!");

            }

            // sek -usd
            if (currencyToExchangeTo == 2)
            {
                newValue = amountToConvert / 8.50m;
                Console.WriteLine("You now have" + newValue.ToString("C2") + " in USD");

            }
        }
        //sek - eur
        if (currencyToExchangeFrom == 2)
        {
            amountToConvert /= 9.49m;
            Console.WriteLine("You now have" + newValue.ToString("C2") + " in EUR");

        }
        //  usd - eur
        if (currencyToExchangeFrom == 3)
        {
            amountToConvert *= 0.90m;
            Console.WriteLine("You now have" + newValue.ToString("C2") + " in EUR");
        }
        return (decimal).001;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you Shannon, yes it is our first assignment on my course. I like how you introduced the switch and the invalid response. What does "C2" stand for? i dont understand this part..Also i just read that to use a decimal you have to have a return type so thank you for clearing that up. why do you have to set the decimal newValue to 0.000?

Comment: C2 tell ToString to format the conversion into a currency string with two decimal places (C for currency 2 for decimals). I just set the original value of the decimal so it would be signed. If you don't assign a value, you will get an unsigned exception the way you have things coded. As I said, I didn't make too many changes - this isn't optimized or generalized - it's just to give you some ideas. Please remember to accept my answer if you feel I've been helpful. Good Luck!

Comment: Ok got it. Its good to see from a different perspective once you've been staring at the screen all day. How do i accept your answer?

Comment: Just click the checkmark below the votes for my answer. I appreciate it, and totally understand the zombie syndrome. Tak care!